# Laravel substr gives unknown column error

Tags: php, laravel

```php
if($userId == '17322'){
                $pdfDataTwo = Pdf::with(['add'])
                    ->whereIn('pdfs.id', [254,258,259,260,263] )
                    ->where('pdfs.licensed', 1)
                    ->where('pdfs.delete_status', 0)
                    ->get(['pdfs.id', 'pdfs.uploaded_by','pdfs.exp_datetime', 'pdfs.licensed', 'pdfs.pharma_id', 'pdfs.code', 'pdfs.rep_code', 'pdfs.pdf_sub_title', 'pdfs.title', 'pdfs.prescribtion', 'pdfs.pdf_file', 'pdfs.pdf_thumb', 'pdfs.pdf_logo', 'pdfs.folder_name', 'pdfs.publisher_id', 'pdfs.status', 'pdfs.file_type', 'pdfs.first_page_bg', 'pdfs.pdf_scale', 'pdfs.ie_pdf_scale', 'pdfs.limit', 'pdfs.first_warning_limit', 'pdfs.sec_warning_limit', 'pdfs.limit_warning_mail_status', 'pdfs.counter', 'pdfs.rep_counter', 'pdfs.created', 'pdfs.totalp', 'pdfs.link_type', 'pdfs.first_popup', 'pdfs.only_first_popup', 'pdfs.first_popup_time', 'pdfs.second_popup_time', 'pdfs.italian_bookmark_popup', 'pdfs.replace_pages', 'pdfs.chk_html', 'pdfs.chapter_thumb_setting', 'pdfs.allow_share', 'pdfs.parent_id', 'pdfs.lastRomanNumber', 'pdfs.popup_email_content_language', 'pdfs.list_email_secure', 'pdfs.certificate', 'pdfs.woocommerce_title_id', 'pdfs.tags', 'pdfs.delete_status', 'pdfs.deleted_at', 'pdfs.allow_print', 'pdfs.print_clicks', 'pdfs.qr_brand', "SUBSTR('pdfs.title', 1 , 20) as 'test' ", 'adds.id', 'adds.pdf_id', 'adds.user_id', 'adds.image', 'adds.title', 'adds.link', 'adds.publisher_link', 'adds.publisher_link_sec', 'adds.publisher_link_third']);
}
```

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
> 'SUBSTR('pdfs.title', 1 , 20)' in 'field list' (SQL: select
> `pdfs`.`id`, `pdfs`.`uploaded_by`,`pdfs`.`exp_datetime`,
> `pdfs`.`licensed`, `pdfs`.`pharma_id`, `pdfs`.`code`,
> `pdfs`.`rep_code`, `pdfs`.`pdf_sub_title`, `pdfs`.`title`,
> `pdfs`.`prescribtion`, `pdfs`.`pdf_file`, `pdfs`.`pdf_thumb`,
> `pdfs`.`pdf_logo`, `pdfs`.`folder_name`, `pdfs`.`publisher_id`,
> `pdfs`.`status`, `pdfs`.`file_type`, `pdfs`.`first_page_bg`,
> `pdfs`.`pdf_scale`, `pdfs`.`ie_pdf_scale`, `pdfs`.`limit`,
> `pdfs`.`first_warning_limit`, `pdfs`.`sec_warning_limit`,
> `pdfs`.`limit_warning_mail_status`, `pdfs`.`counter`,
> `pdfs`.`rep_counter`, `pdfs`.`created`, `pdfs`.`totalp`,
> `pdfs`.`link_type`, `pdfs`.`first_popup`, `pdfs`.`only_first_popup`,
> `pdfs`.`first_popup_time`, `pdfs`.`second_popup_time`,
> `pdfs`.`italian_bookmark_popup`, `pdfs`.`replace_pages`,
> `pdfs`.`chk_html`, `pdfs`.`chapter_thumb_setting`,
> `pdfs`.`allow_share`, `pdfs`.`parent_id`, `pdfs`.`lastRomanNumber`,
> `pdfs`.`popup_email_content_language`, `pdfs`.`list_email_secure`,
> `pdfs`.`certificate`, `pdfs`.`woocommerce_title_id`, `pdfs`.`tags`,
> `pdfs`.`delete_status`, `pdfs`.`deleted_at`, `pdfs`.`allow_print`,
> `pdfs`.`print_clicks`, `pdfs`.`qr_brand`, `SUBSTR('pdfs`.`title', 1 , 20)` as `'test'` , `adds`.`id`, `adds`.`pdf_id`, `adds`.`user_id`,
> `adds`.`image`, `adds`.`title`, `adds`.`link`,
> `adds`.`publisher_link`, `adds`.`publisher_link_sec`,
> `adds`.`publisher_link_third` from `pdfs` where `pdfs`.`id` in (254,
> 258, 259, 260, 263) and `pdfs`.`licensed` = 1 and
> `pdfs`.`delete_status` = 0)

I am trying to get the data but it throws an error which is mentioned above:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SUBSTR being a MySQL function and not an actual column, you need to pass that in with a DB::raw call. Also remove the single quotes on the column name, as that would cause it to be processed as a string, not a column.

```
'pdfs.qr_brand', DB::raw("SUBSTR(pdfs.title, 1 , 20) as test"), 'adds.id',
```